# How to use one throttle for multiple functions?

Tags: javascript, throttling

I searched similar questions, but found no solution so far.

Lets say i have 2 separate fetches, my goal is to throttle them with one timer. Is there a simple way to achieve this? Something like:

```
const throttledFn1 = _.throttle(fn1, 500)
const throttledFn2 = _.throttle(fn2, 500)

useSharedTimer(throttledFn1, throttledFn2)
```

Comment: unclear what you are expecting to happen. You want like one to only fire and not both? Or you want them both to fire at same time?

Comment: goal is to prevent fetches from overlapping, and to be throttled by one timer. To have global control on maximum amount of fetches in certain amount of time

Comment: Then only throttle one function, but a function that takes an argument. That argument should differentiate which fetch will happen. It could be the URL.., or query string, ...

Comment: The thing is, those fetches are not that simple, what they are really in my case is a async functions with a fair amount of props.

Comment: Why not doing something simple/obvious as e.g. `_.throttle((...args) => { fn1(...args);  fn2(...args); } , 500);`

Comment: Well, this code would produce a throttled function, which calls fn1 and fn2, and can be fired no more often then each 500ms. The thing is - these functions are independent, they do not need to be called simultaneously. But they do need to share same throttle timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to just create your own throttle function. You cant access lodash's timeout so its impossible to have full control on shared timers.

most common throttle approaches store timers/setTimeout() in a variable to track whether a function should be cancelled or not, so as long as you can access that variable you can have shared timers between different functions, even with different delays, something like this:

```
export const createTimeout = () => {
  let timeout: any = null;

  const _start = (delay: number) => {
     timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      timeout = null
    }, delay);
  };

  const _persists = () => (timeout !== null);

  return {
    persists: _persists,
    start: _start,
  };
};
```

with this code, you can use it like this

```js
const myTimeout = createTimeout()

function nextPage() {
    if (myTimeout.persists()) return
    // logic here

    myTimeout.start(2000) // start/refresh timeout
}

function prevPage() {
    if (myTimeout.persists()) return
    // logic here
    
    myTimeout.start(3000)

}
```

In this code, whenever I start the timeout, it stores an id from the return value of `setTimeout()` to variable `timeout`, then the callback inside the `setTimeout()` must reassign the value of variable `timeout` in order to determine if the timer is already finished.

Comment: In order to provide an answer to the OP's actual question why not proposing 
 something simple/obvious as e.g. `_.throttle((...args) => { fn1(...args);  fn2(...args); } , 500);`

Comment: @Amia Thank you, this is similar to what i came to eventually. Would not call it minimalistic, but most optimal solution so far. There is a typo in lower code block though - it sholuld be "myTimeout" instead of "timeout" i suppose

Comment: yup, just noticed too, edited now